# Jacoco doesn't produce coverage reports

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I 'm using maven-sure fire plugin to execute tests and Jacoco plugin to generate the coverage reports.  Jacoco does't provide coverage reports and instead fails with the debug log as shown here under.

[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.0:report (jacoco-site) @ util ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

Here is how the maven sure-fire plugin looks.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                     <threadCount>8</threadCount>
                     <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                     </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Here is how the Jacoco plugin looks like.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 8):

Quoting http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html :

> If your project already defines VM arguments for test execution, **be sure that they will include property defined by JaCoCo**.
>
> One of the ways to do this in case of maven-surefire-plugin - is to use syntax for late property evaluation:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <argLine>@{argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> Another way is to define "argLine" as a Maven property rather than as part of the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>   <argLine>-your -extra -arguments</argLine>
> </properties>
> ...
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <!-- no argLine here -->
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

so either define

```
<argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
                    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
```

as property:

```
<build>
  <properties>
    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
                    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
  </properties>
...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- no argLine here -->
```

or add `@{argLine}` to it:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
                    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
```

Comment: You mean I should add that argLine that I had as a property of sure-fire plugin ?

Comment: no luck , I added @{argLine} but still doesn't work. Do you think the issue is something else?

Comment: @user4654 given the small amount of information you provided I don't see any way to guess **what else** is wrong. As already written - make sure that property is taken into account, i.e. run Maven with debug output `mvn -X` and verify that surefire starts JVM with JaCoCo agent. Or read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and  provide complete example.

Comment: I have a similar problem even after adding @{argLine}, however, if I remove the forkCount attribute, I can get jacoco to create a report. I am unsure what the interaction between forkCount and jacoco is and what the correct fix is, but forkCount alone seems to be enough to make jacoco not produce a report in my case.

Comment: @DanSmith as stated at https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html "you must not use a forkCount of 0" other values work just fine

Comment: @Godin: Good call, that's definitely my problem because that is what my project had for a value.