# Jacoco report jeneration failed when i added <argLine> property to surefire plugin configuration

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am working on some old old code to fix the Junits, While doing this I am facing a problem.

Previously in pom.xml there was a plugin configuration like below

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode combine.self="override">pertest</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

with above configuration i can able to see the jacoco coverage file in /target/site  folder after `mvn test`built successfully

But to fix some junits i had add one argLine to above configuration like below

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode combine.self="override">pertest</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After adding this i am not seeing any coverage file in target directory after `mvn test` . Can anybody tell why?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `pom.xml` also contains some `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration?

The plugin uses the `argLine` property to pass the jacoco agent to both surefire and failsafe plugin. If you add your own to the surefire plugin you overwrite those created by the jacoco plugin in the prepare-agent goals.

The [docs](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) describe some alternatives how to solve it.

(Either use the `argLine` as property or use the late evaluation syntax)

If you feel experimental, the property name used to set the jacoco options can be configured, see [propertyName config](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#propertyName). So you could add that property to the surefire parameter as well. But the two options above should be simpler.