# Maven Surefire Plugin: Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1 when testing Java module

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I have same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272870/surefire-maven-plugin-corrupted-stdout-by-directly-writing-to-native-stream-in) but with a different setup. In my case I am trying to test code that I have written as a Java Module. I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modularity-unit-testing). Accordingly I have configured my `pom.xml` as follows (and I am using Junit 5 if it matters):

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--add-modules my.mod --add-opens my.mod/my.mod=org.junit.platform.commons --add-reads my.mod=org.junit.jupiter.api --patch-module my.mod=target/test-classes</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I run, first I get a warning:

```
[WARNING] Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file
```

and then I get this error:

```
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /xxx && /Library/Java/jdk-20.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --add-modules my.mod --add-opens my.mod/my.mod=org.junit.platform.commons --add-reads my.mod=org.junit.jupiter.api --patch-module my.mod=target/test-classes ...
```

I read the solutions in the linked question and here are some of the things I have tried:

- If I add a `<forkNode implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.SurefireForkNodeFactory"/>` maven hangs. Sometimes I also see this message printed on the console and in the log:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
```

- I tried using `3.0.0-M6`, `3.0.0-M4` and `3.1.2` (latest) and get pretty much same behavior

How can I fix this?