# Why don't work Jacoco? I hope I did everything right

Tags: travis-ci, jacoco

https://github.com/Teemitze/TelegramBot

Why is Jacoco statistics not displayed? A warning appears during Assembly

> Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your project](https://github.com/Teemitze/TelegramBot/blob/93353edd45575037d3b2ceb24a5fff9a8f53869a/pom.xml#L36-L42)

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

whereas similarly to many other questions here such as "[Jacoco doesn't produce coverage reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581414/jacoco-doesnt-produce-coverage-reports/49581538#49581538)" and quoting [JaCoCo documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html):

> If your project already defines VM arguments for test execution, **be sure that they will include property defined by JaCoCo**.
>
> One of the ways to do this in case of maven-surefire-plugin - is to use syntax for late property evaluation:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <argLine>@{argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> Another way is to define "argLine" as a Maven property rather than as part of the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>   <argLine>-your -extra -arguments</argLine>
> </properties>
> ...
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <!-- no argLine here -->
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```